# We have 2 lines. How can we get point where that 2 lines intersect with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, line, points, intersect

1st line A(x1, y1) is starting point and B(x2,y2) is end point
2st line A(x2,y2) is starting point and B(x2,y2) is end point

I need a function which can return the point where these 2 lines will intersect.

Comment: Two lines intersect with Javascript. o_0

Comment: This is pure Maths question and it has nothing specific to do with JavaScript. Please try asking in https://math.stackexchange.com/.Besides, provide any work or code tried so far. SO is not going to do your work

Comment: I need function for that in js

Comment: You have two problems here: 1) algorithm about finding the intersection of two segments. 2) How to implement that in javascript. They are two separate problems (that should be asked in separate questions) and the first one is not even on-topic in stackoverflow, so this question is actually off-topic. Once you know an algorithm and you have tried to implement it, you can ask here if you have problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a good read: [How to check if two given line segments intersect](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-two-given-line-segments-intersect/)

and here's a way to do it using JavaScript:

```
var Point = function(valA, valB) {
  this.x = valA;
  this.y = valB;
};

function lineIntersection(pointA, pointB, pointC, pointD) {
  var z1 = (pointA.x - pointB.x);
  var z2 = (pointC.x - pointD.x);
  var z3 = (pointA.y - pointB.y);
  var z4 = (pointC.y - pointD.y);
  var dist = z1 * z4 - z3 * z2;
  if (dist == 0) {
    return null;
  }
  var tempA = (pointA.x * pointB.y - pointA.y * pointB.x);
  var tempB = (pointC.x * pointD.y - pointC.y * pointD.x);
  var xCoor = (tempA * z2 - z1 * tempB) / dist;
  var yCoor = (tempA * z4 - z3 * tempB) / dist;

  if (xCoor < Math.min(pointA.x, pointB.x) || xCoor > Math.max(pointA.x, pointB.x) ||
    xCoor < Math.min(pointC.x, pointD.x) || xCoor > Math.max(pointC.x, pointD.x)) {
    return null;
  }
  if (yCoor < Math.min(pointA.y, pointB.y) || yCoor > Math.max(pointA.y, pointB.y) ||
    yCoor < Math.min(pointC.y, pointD.y) || yCoor > Math.max(pointC.y, pointD.y)) {
    return null;
  }

  return new Point(xCoor, yCoor);
}

console.log(lineIntersection(new Point(40, 0), new Point(180, 140), new Point(60, 120), new Point(180, 40)));
```